# ssh login with putty key from mac

Tags: ssh, mac, putty, keys

I am trying to login to a server from a Mac with a key I made with putty (Win). The output, some of which is shown below looks like it is trying , but I dont have a passphrase, so I just hit enter when the dialo box comes up, so I dont know how to get it to accept a blank passphrase. I know it works on my Win machine,no password or passphrase.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/michael/.ssh/b.ppk
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug2: bad passphrase given, try again...
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug2: bad passphrase given, try again...
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert your Putty Private Key (.ppk) to something resembling a standard SSH key - `puttygen` can do this for you (cf. [This Link](http://leadingedgescripts.co.uk/server-administration/how-to-convert-your-putty-ppk-private-key-to-a-normal-ssh-key-you-can-use-on-an-apple-mac/), or ask The Google about puttygen...)

Comment: Can I still use it to login with putty after I convert it.

Comment: You will wind up with two copies of the "same" key (in different file formats) - a .ppk key used by putty, and a (more standard) OpenSSH key usable by the ssh client on your Mac, Linux boxen, BSD machines, etc.

Comment: Is there any OS X application that can do the conversion?

Comment: @MartijnHeemels Not that I know of - but presumably if you have a `.ppk` private key you also have PuTTY and a Windows machine, and can therefore use the PuTTY tools to do the conversion :)

Comment: Yeah, a Windows machine is always around the corner somewhere. Except when there isn't :-) Yesterday, all I had was a Macbook Pro and a .ppk file. Had to RDP into a Windows machine to convert the key, which led me to wonder frustratedly why Putty would choose its own keyfile format.

Answer (score 3):

[This post from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3932540/1068283) gives an answer about converting your PEM key to PPK, using OSX terminal:

```
sudo port install putty
puttygen privatekey.ppk -O private-openssh -o privatekey.pem
```